# Katalon: Test case is failing in Ubuntu but working in Windows

Tags: katalon-studio

we have a test suite of Katalon with around 16 cases. It's a web service testing.

All the test cases are working fine in windows however, while migrating to ubuntu one test case is failing, remaining all are passing.

I am getting the ​following exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Response object is null"

I have verified the object is there and everything seems to be perfect.

```
2019-04-04 03:20:14.478 ERROR c.k.k.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain  - ❌ Unable to send request and verify the response (Root cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request object is null
at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.helper.WebServiceCommonHelper.checkRequestObject(WebServiceCommonHelper.java:22)
at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.builtin.SendRequestAndVerifyKeyword$_sendRequestAndVerify_closure1.doCall(SendRequestAndVerifyKeyword.groovy:43)
at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.builtin.SendRequestAndVerifyKeyword$_sendRequestAndVerify_closure1.call(SendRequestAndVerifyKeyword.groovy)
at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain.runKeyword(KeywordMain.groovy:66)
at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.builtin.SendRequestAndVerifyKeyword.sendRequestAndVerify(SendRequestAndVerifyKeyword.groovy:42)
at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.builtin.SendRequestAndVerifyKeyword.execute(SendRequestAndVerifyKeyword.groovy:37)
at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:56)
at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords.sendRequestAndVerify(WSBuiltInKeywords.groovy:65)
at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords$sendRequestAndVerify$2.call(Unknown Source)
at Update_Bto.run(Update_Bto:21)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:331)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:322)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:301)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:293)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:227)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestCaseMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:129)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestSuiteMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:112)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.execute(TestSuiteExecutor.java:81)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.startTestSuite(TestCaseMain.java:157)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$startTestSuite$0.call(Unknown Source)
at TempTestSuite1554348006381.run(TempTestSuite1554348006381.groovy:35)
```

)
2019-04-04 03:20:14.482 DEBUG testcase.Update_Bto                      - 3: verifyResponseStatusCode(updateBtoResponse, 204)
2019-04-04 03:20:14.485 ERROR c.k.k.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain  - ❌ Unable to verify response status code (Root cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Response object is null
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.helper.WebServiceCommonHelper.checkResponseObject(WebServiceCommonHelper.java:29)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.builtin.VerifyResponseStatusCodeKeyword$_verifyResponseStatusCode_closure1.doCall(VerifyResponseStatusCodeKeyword.groovy:38)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.builtin.VerifyResponseStatusCodeKeyword$_verifyResponseStatusCode_closure1.call(VerifyResponseStatusCodeKeyword.groovy)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain.runKeyword(KeywordMain.groovy:66)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.builtin.VerifyResponseStatusCodeKeyword.verifyResponseStatusCode(VerifyResponseStatusCodeKeyword.groovy:37)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.builtin.VerifyResponseStatusCodeKeyword.execute(VerifyResponseStatusCodeKeyword.groovy:32)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:56)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords.verifyResponseStatusCode(WSBuiltInKeywords.groovy:212)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords$verifyResponseStatusCode$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at Update_Bto.run(Update_Bto:25)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:331)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:322)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:301)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:293)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:227)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestCaseMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:129)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestSuiteMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:112)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.execute(TestSuiteExecutor.java:81)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.startTestSuite(TestCaseMain.java:157)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$startTestSuite$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at TempTestSuite1554348006381.run(TempTestSuite1554348006381.groovy:35)
)
2019-04-04 03:20:14.486 ERROR c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - ❌ verifyResponseStatusCode(updateBtoResponse, 204) FAILED.
Reason:
com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Unable to send request and verify the response (Root cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request object is null
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.helper.WebServiceCommonHelper.checkRequestObject(WebServiceCommonHelper.java:22)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.builtin.SendRequestAndVerifyKeyword$_sendRequestAndVerify_closure1.doCall(SendRequestAndVerifyKeyword.groovy:43)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.builtin.SendRequestAndVerifyKeyword$_sendRequestAndVerify_closure1.call(SendRequestAndVerifyKeyword.groovy)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain.runKeyword(KeywordMain.groovy:66)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.builtin.SendRequestAndVerifyKeyword.sendRequestAndVerify(SendRequestAndVerifyKeyword.groovy:42)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.builtin.SendRequestAndVerifyKeyword.execute(SendRequestAndVerifyKeyword.groovy:37)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:56)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords.sendRequestAndVerify(WSBuiltInKeywords.groovy:65)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords$sendRequestAndVerify$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at Update_Bto.run(Update_Bto:21)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:331)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:322)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:301)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:293)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:227)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestCaseMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:129)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestSuiteMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:112)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.execute(TestSuiteExecutor.java:81)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.startTestSuite(TestCaseMain.java:157)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$startTestSuite$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at TempTestSuite1554348006381.run(TempTestSuite1554348006381.groovy:35)
)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain.stepFailed(KeywordMain.groovy:37)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain.stepFailed(KeywordMain.groovy)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain.runKeyword(KeywordMain.groovy:68)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.builtin.SendRequestAndVerifyKeyword.sendRequestAndVerify(SendRequestAndVerifyKeyword.groovy:42)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.builtin.SendRequestAndVerifyKeyword.execute(SendRequestAndVerifyKeyword.groovy:37)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:56)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords.sendRequestAndVerify(WSBuiltInKeywords.groovy:65)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords$sendRequestAndVerify$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at Update_Bto.run(Update_Bto:21)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:331)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:322)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:301)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:293)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:227)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestCaseMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:129)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestSuiteMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:112)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.execute(TestSuiteExecutor.java:81)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.startTestSuite(TestCaseMain.java:157)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$startTestSuite$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at TempTestSuite1554348006381.run(TempTestSuite1554348006381.groovy:35)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request object is null
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.helper.WebServiceCommonHelper.checkRequestObject(WebServiceCommonHelper.java:22)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.builtin.SendRequestAndVerifyKeyword$_sendRequestAndVerify_closure1.doCall(SendRequestAndVerifyKeyword.groovy:43)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.builtin.SendRequestAndVerifyKeyword$_sendRequestAndVerify_closure1.call(SendRequestAndVerifyKeyword.groovy)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain.runKeyword(KeywordMain.groovy:66)
    ... 19 more

Comment: Please, post the test case that is failing and the whole exception stack.

Comment: Hey Mate, i have added the full trace to main post.

Comment: Share your test case code, too.

Comment: @MateMrše, its pretty easy that is calling the service and testing the response code.  //UpdateBto
'Update Btos Object Passed and Response Received'
updateBtoResponse = WS.sendRequestAndVerify(findTestObject('BTO/Update BTOS'))
//verifying Update bto response
'verifying response status code'
WS.verifyResponseStatusCode(updateBtoResponse, 204)

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with network settings with Ubuntu? What is in `BTO/Update BTOS` object?

Comment: i do not agree its a network issue as we have 16 cases and 15 are running fine. BTO/Update BTOS is a webservice object